# JSch - command not being sent to shell?

Tags: java, jsch

I'm working on a project to restart something within a screen on a remote server using JSch... however I'm running into an issue. It will send the first 2 commands 100% of the time, but the 3rd command will only be sent some of the time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void stopServer(String name, String ip, String passwd)
{
    try {
        Session session = Main.jsch.getSession("user",ip,22);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(passwd);
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelShell cs = (ChannelShell) channel;
        cs.setPty(true);
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream());
        PrintStream dataOut = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());
        dataOut.println("screen -x "+name);
        dataOut.flush();
        dataOut.println("stop");
        dataOut.flush();
        String line = dataIn.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        while(true) {
            line = dataIn.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line.contains("\"quit\""))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        dataOut.println("quit");
        dataOut.flush();
        System.out.println("Shutdown");
        dataIn.close();
        dataOut.close();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This sends the screen -x 'name' and the stop 100% of the time from what I've seen, but the 'quit' command only actually gets sent/understood by the console a fraction of the time. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix  this in a way that doesn't use the shell channel, but it is reliable enough that it works:

```
//Start EXEC
            ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            ce.setCommand("screen -S " + name + " -X stuff 'quit\n'");
            ce.setInputStream(null);
            ce.setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in=ce.getInputStream();

            ce.connect();

            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if(i<0)break;
                    //System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if(ce.isClosed()){
                    if(in.available()>0) continue;
                    //System.out.println("exit-status: "+ce.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            ce.disconnect();
            //STOP EXEC
```

As much as this doesn't work along the original vein of the problem, it fixed it for me.

Comment: Using "exec" channel is definitely more appropriate and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

1. If an exception gets thrown sometime before the "quit" command gets sent, then the quit command will never get sent.
2. If the while loop never breaks, then that will prevent the "quit"
   command from being sent too.

Comment: I know it's not throwing an exception and that it's not getting stuck in the while loop because the print after the while is printing out to console.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer Then maybe the remote server isn't properly handling the command? Or maybe it takes the server some time to process the command?

Comment: That looks so much like a codereview answer. Why don't you come over and review a little sometime?